# What is the physical significance of the Curie constant?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, magnetic-moment

What is the physical significance of the [Curie constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_constant)? I understand it depends on the effective moment of the ion and hence must be some measure of it, but what is it exactly? Like some average moment per magnetic atom or average moment of the solid overall? Or what? If it were to be explained non-mathematically, then how would you define it?

Comment: I am not sure if the Curie constant is a measure of that. I believe the Weiss constant is a measure of interaction strength in a solid, which would talk about how much it can sustain alignment against thermal fluctuations. Any clarifications? And rather than what quantity it can be correlated with, I would like to know what it IS or what it means...

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is a measure of how strongly a material is able to sustain magnetic alignment despite thermal fluctuations.

Which will obviously be determined by how strongly each atoms couples to the magnetic field (magnetic moment and angular momentum) and the density of such atoms.

Answer (score 1):

The curie constant is a material constant which tells you the "size" of the magnetic susceptibility of a substance according to the curie-law (or curie-weiss-law).

Answer (score -1):

The temperature above which a ferromagnetic material loses its ferromagnetism and become paramagnetic.